# Algorithms that find the right file to serve from an HTTP Server

Tags: html, algorithm, http

I am currently building my own HTTP-Server, in which I now want to serve the correct File to the user.
What I have is a 2d Array that contains the accepted mime types and their weight:

```
[("text/html", 0.9), ("application/xhtml+xml", 0.9), ("application/xml", 0.9), ("image/avif", 0.8), ("image/webp", 0.8), ("*/*", 0.8)]
```

And the path from which the HTML GET was started:

```
/
/test
/route/this
```

What sort of algorithms are used by other static file servers?
**Keep in mind:** The goal isn't to just use a library or something, but to write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If writing in Python, you can use the built-in package [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) to transform mimetypes to file extensions. Then the exact algorithm will depend on your needs, but this should be a good start:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()

# Base directory where the files are located.
base = Path('.')

# Accept header from the client. The numbers are relative priorities.
accept = [("text/html", 0.9), ("application/xhtml+xml", 0.9), ("application/xml", 0.9), ("image/avif", 0.8), ("image/webp", 0.8), ("*/*", 0.8)]

# The path requested by the client.
http_path = '/a'

# For each mimetype, sorted by preference.
for mimetype, _ in sorted(accept, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    # Find all extensions for this mimetype.
    for extension in mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(mimetype):
        # Check for both exact path, and files named "index.*".
        for prefix in ['', '/index']:
            # Check if there exists a file with this extension.
            file = base / f'{http_path.strip('/')}{prefix}{extension}'
            if file.exists():
                print(f'Found {file} of type {mimetype}')
```

Comment: Holy cow. That’s *O(n^3)*

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon No? It's O(accepted mimetypes * average extensions per mimetype * prefixes), but only one of those is a variable input (accepted mimetypes), and prefixes is fixed to 2. With OP's example there's 6 accepted mimetypes, a handful of extensions on average, and two prefixes.

Comment: What you failed to point out is that *average extensions per mimetype* is actually *all extensions per mimetype* which can range between *0 to 100*. I believe there are better algorithms. I would imploy the OP to check out that used by *C++ Drogon*. You will have to understand C++ to understand the algorithm though.
*It's all trial and error!*

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Not in Python. `Counter(mimetypes.types_map.values()).most_common(1)` tells me that the mimetype with most extensions is `application/octet-stream`, with just 7 extensions. Sure, precomputing the mimetypes for local files is probably better. But it's not O(n^3) and mimetypes in Python don't have 100 extensions.

Comment: If `application/octet-stream` is associated with just 7 extensions, then I would not trust the mapping to be anywhere close to complete. Not even half complete. Yes you are right that it isn’t *O(n^3)* but it is *O(n • k • 2)* where *k is possibly large*. This still gives us a poor algorithm.

Comment: It's interesting that there is no defined algorithm for this. But I have to kind of agree with @BoppreH. There aren't a lot of accepted MIME types and probably also not a lot of potential files on an HTTP request.